# ERAlchemy cannot connect to database

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I don't understand the syntax to call the render feature of ERAlchemy (https://pypi.org/project/ERAlchemy  see "Usage for Python"). I am using Python 2.7, sqlite3, and PyCharm. I have ERAlchemy, GraphViz, and PyGraphViz installed.

I am trying the following, but it cannot connect to the database:

```
from eralchemy import render_er
render_er("sqlite:///C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\Work\\pythonsqlite.db", 'erd_from_sqlite.png')
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/myname/Documents/Work/_sql_functions_rev0.py", line 81, in <module>
    render_er("sqlite:///C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\Work\\pythonsqlite.db", 'erd_from_sqlite.png')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\eralchemy\main.py", line 236, in render_er
    intermediary_to_output(tables, relationships, output)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\eralchemy\main.py", line 75, in intermediary_to_schema
    graph.draw(path=output, prog='dot', format=extension)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1474, in draw
    data = self._run_prog(prog, args)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1308, in _run_prog
    runprog = r'"%s"' % self._get_prog(prog)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1295, in _get_prog
    raise ValueError("Program %s not found in path." % prog)
ValueError: Program dot not found in path.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Found the answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-weka-wrapper/b7L-VTc9BAM)

had to find the folder with "dot.exe" and add it to the environment variables -> system variables -> path